# Show that the Maclaurin Polynomials for f(x) = ln (1+x) are . . .

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$T_n(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \dotsb + \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^n}{n}$$

I of course understand how to show that it equals the first two terms, but so far have been unable to prove that it equals the 'general term' or the last term.

Comment: I would upvote all of yours but I don't think my reputation is high enough.  I am a bit confused about your answer, but that's probably my problem.

Comment: Don't feel pressured to upvote or accept any particular answer. You are welcome to leave the answers unaccepted for as long as you want. Ideally, you accept the one that is most useful to you. That could take an hour, or it can take a few days. It's up to you. By the way, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea where you even started.

Comment: LOL !!!! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^{n}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+x)  = \frac{1}{1+x} = (1+x)^{-1} \rightarrow \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} \ln(1+x)= (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!(1+x)^{-n} \\ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(1+x) |_{x=0}= (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!
$$

$$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} (x)^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} (x)^{n}
$$

Comment: for maclaurin series you need to evalute $x_0 = 0$ so evaluating the derivative $(1+x)^{-n}$ vanishes if $x=0$ and the denominator results for $n! = n (n-1)!$

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=ln(x+1)$ then the derivatives are:

\begin{equation}
f^{(1)}=\frac{1}{x+1}\\f^{(2)}=\frac{-1}{(x+1)^2}\\f^{(3)}=\frac{(-1)(-2)}{(x+1)^3}=\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\\f^{(4)}=\frac{2(-3)}{(x+1)^4}=\frac{-6}{(x+1)^4}\\f^{(5)}=\frac{2*3*4}{(x+1)^5}
\end{equation}

and so on...We can see that n-derivative will be:

\begin{equation}
f^{(n)}=(-1)^{(n-1)}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)^n}
\end{equation}

If you calculate the derivatives in $x=0$ and multiply for $x^n$ you obtain the formula.

Comment: Hi.  I understand how you found the general formula for the nth derivative but I am not quite sure about how to use that to get find the final formula for the nth term.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
the general derivative of $\ln(1+x)$ is
$$f^{(n)}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}\quad{\text n>0}$$
at $x=0$, the derivative equation becomes
$$f^{(n)}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+0)^n}=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!$$

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that information.

Comment: the Maclaurin series takes the form $f(x)=f(0)+{\frac {f'(0)}{1!}}(x)+{\frac {f''(0)}{2!}}(x)^{2}+{\frac {f'''(0)}{3!}}(x)^{3}+\cdots .$ which depends on the derivatives at $x=0$

Comment: Hmmm. So do I plug 0 into the formula for the general derivative and and then divide it by n! and multiply it by (x^n)?  Sorry, I am really confused.

Comment: yes, as you have said

Comment: I get stuck, don't know how to simplify it further to get the final nth term.

Answer (score 0):

We use
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+x}
$.

We have
$\sum_{k=0}^n t^k
=\frac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}
$.
Putting $-t$ for $t$,
$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kt^k
=\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}}{1+t}
$
so that
$\frac{1}{1+t}
=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kt^k+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}}{1+t}
$.

Integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^x dt\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kt^k+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}}{1+t}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\int_0^x t^k dt+\int_0^x dt\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^x dt\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{k}}{k}+e_n(x)
\qquad\text{where } e_n(x) =(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^x dt\frac{t^{n+1}}{1+t}\\
\end{array}
$

This is the MacLaurin series
for $\ln(1+x)$
with an explicit error term
which is nice).

To show that
$e_n(x) \to 0$
as $n \to \infty$
for
$0 < x < 1$,
note that

$\begin{array}\\
|e_n(x)| 
&=\big|\int_0^x dt\frac{t^{n+1}}{1+t}\big|\\
&<\big|\int_0^x t^{n+1}dt|\\
&=\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\\
&< \frac1{n+2}\\
& \to 0\\
\end{array}
$

As is often the case,
my answer is not original.
It is taken from
"100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics"
by Heinrich Dörrie,
available for
less than $15 US
from Amazon.

I have enjoyed and recommend this book.

Comment: nice, my case is kinda the opposite it's almost always (actually always) the case that my answer is original :)